# Proposal: add the reverse image search tutorial to the [faq]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The reverse image search tutorial: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-can-i-identify-an-anime-using-reverse-image-search

I propose that this question be tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) so that it is easier to find. I don't really expect that the users *asking* the low-effort identification questions that are easily solved by reverse image search will find this tutorial even if it is tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), but this makes it easier for the *rest of us* to point this tutorial out to them.

Answer (score 3):

I've added a link to said tutorial in our [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Wait, why did you tag _this_ question as [meta-tag:faq]?

Comment: No reason really.